# Angular Project creation

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

I have a node project which is running fine. I need to create a angular project inside that node project

So that i can run backend and front end

Could you please suggest the way of creating an angular project inside a node projet

Comment: Please be more clear what you want? Do you just want to create an Angular Project inside the node folder or you want to run node and angular project at once with one command?

Comment: I want to run node and angular project at once

Comment: Here you go, https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

with this package you can run both the packages concurrently... Thanks :) Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate project for front end. Join both back end and front end with API.
For creation of new angular project read this doc https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: can you suggest the API please

Comment: Create your own api's requests in node to connect angular project.

Answer (score 0):

For creating an angular project inside node project folder.

Open path of your node project(where you want to add angular project) in terminal and run angular cli command: `ng new 'project_name'` for creating a new angular project.

You can run both frontend and backend server simultaneously by running respective commands of starting servers: `ng serve` for frontend and `node 'index/app.js'` for backend.

Answer (score 0):

Steps (in Terminal):

```
cd <path_of_your_node_project>
```

Then :

```
ng new <project_name>
```

!! Use :
`ng serve` (to run your angular project)

`nodemon app.js` (to run your node project)